# How to set database connection in spring boot application on cloud

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to connect to postgresql in a spring boot application. I have kept db config. in application.properties.But access to db is getting denied.Though db details are correct example db url ,password and user.

I have two components. The the 1st component is java appliacaion from where I am hitting this url which is a spring boot application. I want retrieve some data from the server DB. Locally it is working fine.
[Please refer stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Iq4.png)

Comment: 1. Show us the exception trace.
2. Does the Cloud DB allow external connections? With MySQL, you need to set it explicitly to allow other than localhost to connect to a DB. -
3. Something similar should be with PostgreSQL.
4. I would suggest to first get your app running on local DB and then you can create another profile for cloud say application-cloud.properties and then try it with the cloud.

Comment: I have moved my answer to comment above.

Comment: Please refer stack trace.

Comment: seems more like your DB is not reachable from where you've deployed your java app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a spring boot issue. This is a Postgres issue. Looks like the userid which you are using to login dont have access to the tables or the packages. Please use GRANT statement in pgsql to provide grants for the user to all the objects/tables that you need. Please try to access via a DB client like PGAdmin, AquqStudio etc.